# Why does sorting strings with numbers have a different result than just sorting the numbers?

Tags: sorting, language-agnostic

This is the python output:

-> sorted(["0", "-1", "1", "-100", "100"])

-> ['-1', '-100', '0', '1', '100']

My expectation was ['-100', '-1', '0', '1', '100'], since -1 > -100 in the number scale.
Why is -100 treated as a higher value than -1 here ? I just want to understand the logic.

Comment: Because they are strings that just happen to represent integers.

Comment: All string comparisons happen character-by-character left-to-right -- in pretty much every programming language there is -- so when your strings contain integers, that means they operate digit-by-digit left-to-right. That provides a very different result than numeric value comparisons.

Comment: For the same reason that "he" comes before "hello" in alphabetical order.

Comment: So, for example, when you compare "10" to "2", the first step is to compare "1" to "2", and because 2 is bigger than 1, you're done immediately and don't need to look at any other digits. Again, this isn't just Python -- it works this way in C, in bash (when using `[[ $str1 > $str2 ]]`), in Ruby, and basically everywhere else.

Comment: You're  sorting strings - Python has no idea that you _think_ of them as representing integers. If you want to sort integers instead, you have to convert the strings to integers first. For example, `sorted(map(int, ["0", "-1", "1", "-100", "100"]))` produces `[-100, -1, 0, 1, 100]`.

Comment: Strings don't sort the same as integers.  `aaaaa` comes before `b` in the dictionary, but `11111` is bigger than `2`.

Comment: @JohnGordon - I think you meant the string '11111' would be less than the string '2'.

Comment: Note that '-1' is less than '0' because '-' is 0x2D and '0' is 0x30 (in ASCII). However, '+' => 0x2B and is less than '-' => hex 0x2D, so '+100" is less than '-100'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorting strings is generally done -- across all languages, not just Python -- with the same algorithm, one that operates character-by-character.

1. Start at the first character of each input string.

   - Is the first character on the left larger than the one on the right? Then decide that the first string as a whole is larger.
   - Is the first character on the right larger than the one on the left? Then decide that the second string as a whole is larger.
   - Are both characters identical? Then we're not done yet.
2. Move on to the next character and repeat.

   - Is there *no* next character on one of the two sides? Then the side with the shortest string is smaller.

---

Following that algorithm, `'10'` is smaller than `'2'` because `'1'` is smaller than `'2'`.

If you want a result that reflects numeric comparison, you need to compare values *as numbers*, not as strings.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed clarification, this was one of the General coding questions I encountered. I was trying to understand the logic behind this behavior, since the reasoning is not intuitive if you know nothing about string comparison.